# Firebase Crashlytics - uploadCrashlyticsSymbolFile, OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

I'm using Firebase Crashlytics to catch my ndk crashes, I've followed this tutorial, so using exactly the same setup. https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/ndk-reports

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ndk:17.0.0'

classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.1.1'
```

And

```
firebaseCrashlytics {
     nativeSymbolUploadEnabled true

     strippedNativeLibsDir "build/intermediates/stripped_native_libs/path/out/lib"
     unstrippedNativeLibsDir "build/intermediates/unstripped_native_libs/path/out/lib"

}
```

Since it is heap error I tried

```
 org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx14096m

 dexOptions.with {
     javaMaxHeapSize = "14g"
 }
```

When I run the `uploadCrashlyticsSymbolFileMyAppName`

Script fails at  `app:generateCrashlyticsSymbolFileMyAppDebug`

My unstripped and stripped libraries is over 80mb I'm sure that is the reason.

**Full stacktrace**

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:generateCrashlyticsSymbolFileMyAppName'.
> Java heap space

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:generateCrashlyticsSymbolFileMyAppName'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:205)
        at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:263)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:203)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:184)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:114)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:41)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:372)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:359)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:352)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:338)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:127)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:191)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:182)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:124)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.ndk.internal.dwarf.DwarfDataParser.interleave(DwarfDataParser.java:355)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.ndk.internal.dwarf.DwarfDataParser.interleaveRanges(DwarfDataParser.java:330)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.ndk.internal.dwarf.DwarfDataParser.processChildDebugInfoEntries(DwarfDataParser.java:285)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.ndk.internal.dwarf.DwarfDataParser.processChildDebugInfoEntries(DwarfDataParser.java:286)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.ndk.internal.dwarf.DwarfDataParser.processCompilationUnit(DwarfDataParser.java:204)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.ndk.internal.dwarf.DwarfDataParser.readCompilationUnit(DwarfDataParser.java:183)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.ndk.internal.dwarf.DwarfDataParser.readCompilationUnit(DwarfDataParser.java:149)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.ndk.internal.dwarf.DwarfDataParser.parse(DwarfDataParser.java:73)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.ndk.internal.elf.ElfDataParser.parseElf(ElfDataParser.java:132)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.ndk.internal.elf.ElfDataParser.parse(ElfDataParser.java:101)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.ndk.internal.elf.ElfDataParser.parse(ElfDataParser.java:39)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.ndk.internal.csym.ElfCSymFactory.createCSymFromFile(ElfCSymFactory.java:92)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.ndk.internal.csym.NdkCSymGenerator.generateCodeMappings(NdkCSymGenerator.java:101)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.ndk.internal.csym.NdkCSymGenerator.generateCodeMappings(NdkCSymGenerator.java:90)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.ndk.internal.csym.NdkCSymGenerator.generateFromDirectories(NdkCSymGenerator.java:44)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.Buildtools.generateSymbolsFromDirectory(Buildtools.java:213)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.Buildtools$generateSymbolsFromDirectory$3.call(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.gradle.tasks.GenerateSymbolFileTask.generateSymbols(GenerateSymbolFileTask.groovy:45)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:104)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:49)
```

**Similar issue from fabric**

[Crashlytics Generate Symbols gradle step fails: GC Overhead Limit Exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57623793/crashlytics-generate-symbols-gradle-step-fails-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded)

[Error while uploading symbols to Firebase Crashlytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57931385/error-while-uploading-symbols-to-firebase-crashlytics)

Github issue is here https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/1588

Edit : follow the github issue please, we told that that is known bug.

Answer (score 0):

Crashlytics could not find NDK build tasks on which to depend. You many need to manually enforce task dependencies for generateCrashlyticsSymbolFileDebug
Crashlytics could not find NDK build tasks on which to depend. You many need to manually enforce task dependencies for generateCrashlyticsSymbolFileRelease

> Task :app:generateCrashlyticsSymbolFileDebug
> Crashlytics found no object files in /Users/wwy/Desktop/aolclient_new/proj.android-studio/jni/obj. Is the -androidNdkOut setting configured correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The `OutOfMemoryError` should be fixed with the latest version of the `firebase-crashlytics-gradle` plugin:

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.4.1
```

Release notes: https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android